# Запись данных в открытый Excel файл с помощью COM OLE C++

Tags: c++, com, ole

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли у кого пример кода чтения и записи данных из/в открытый ексель файл с помощью COM/OLE на чистом С++.

Есть микрософтовский пример: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/216686/how-to-automate-excel-from-c-without-using-mfc-or-import

Он создает ексель файл и записывает в него данные, но как записать данные в уже в Открытый ексель файл, как этот ексель файл отловить, такого примера нет, а доработать/изменить микрософтовский примера под свою задачу, для меня на данный момент, к сожалению совершенно не возможно, настолько там все сложно.

Может кто нибудь делал нечто подобное.

Comment: У вас ссылка сломанная...

Comment: Прошу прощения,  вот рабочая: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/216686/how-to-automate-excel-from-c-without-using-mfc-or-import

Comment: Лучше внесите её в вопрос, там есть ссылка "править"...

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подключения к запущенному экземпляру Excel необходимо использовать вызов GetActiveObject вместо CoCreateInstance. Далее, для получения доступа к открытому документу нужно заменить вызов метода Add на вызов свойства Item с индексом 1. Получаем такой код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ole2.h> // OLE2 Definitions

// AutoWrap() - Automation helper function...
HRESULT AutoWrap(int autoType, VARIANT *pvResult, IDispatch *pDisp, LPOLESTR ptName, int cArgs...) {
    // Begin variable-argument list...
    va_list marker;
    va_start(marker, cArgs);

    if (!pDisp) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "NULL IDispatch passed to AutoWrap()", "Error", 0x10010);
        _exit(0);
    }

    // Variables used...
    DISPPARAMS dp = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
    DISPID dispidNamed = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;
    DISPID dispID;
    HRESULT hr;
    char buf[200];
    char szName[200];


    // Convert down to ANSI
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ptName, -1, szName, 256, NULL, NULL);

    // Get DISPID for name passed...
    hr = pDisp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &ptName, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispID);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames(\"%s\") failed w/err 0x%08lx", szName, hr);        
        getchar();
        _exit(0);
        return hr;
    }


    // Allocate memory for arguments...
    VARIANT *pArgs = new VARIANT[cArgs + 1];
    // Extract arguments...
    for (int i = 0; i < cArgs; i++) {
        pArgs[i] = va_arg(marker, VARIANT);
    }

    // Build DISPPARAMS
    dp.cArgs = cArgs;
    dp.rgvarg = pArgs;

    // Handle special-case for property-puts!
    if (autoType & DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT) {
        dp.cNamedArgs = 1;
        dp.rgdispidNamedArgs = &dispidNamed;
    }

    // Make the call!
    hr = pDisp->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, autoType, &dp, pvResult, NULL, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("IDispatch::Invoke(\"%s\"=%08lx) failed w/err 0x%08lx", szName, dispID, hr);     
        getchar();
        _exit(0);
        return hr;
    }
    // End variable-argument section...
    va_end(marker);

    delete[] pArgs;

    return hr;
}

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Initialize COM for this thread...
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Get CLSID for our server...
    CLSID clsid;
    HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Excel.Application", &clsid);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ::MessageBoxA(NULL, "CLSIDFromProgID() failed", "Error", 0x10010);
        return -1;
    }

    IUnknown* pUnk;
    hr = GetActiveObject(clsid, NULL, &pUnk);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ::MessageBoxA(NULL, "GetActiveObject failed!", "Error", 0x10010);
        return -2;
    }

    IDispatch *pXlApp;
    hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void**)&pXlApp);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ::MessageBoxA(NULL, "QueryInterface failed!", "Error", 0x10010);
        return -2;
    }

    // Make it visible (i.e. app.visible = 1)
    {

        VARIANT x;
        x.vt = VT_I4;
        x.lVal = 1;
        AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pXlApp, (LPOLESTR)L"Visible", 1, x);
    }

    // Get Workbooks collection
    IDispatch *pXlBooks;
    {
        VARIANT result;
        VariantInit(&result);
        AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlApp, (LPOLESTR)L"Workbooks", 0);
        pXlBooks = result.pdispVal;
    }   

    //Open workbook
    IDispatch *pXlBook;
    {
        VARIANT result;
        VariantInit(&result);

        VARIANT index;
        VariantInit(&index);
        index.vt = VT_INT;
        index.intVal = 1;       

        AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlBooks, (LPOLESTR)L"Item",1, index);
        pXlBook = result.pdispVal;
        VariantClear(&index);
    }   

    // Create a 15x15 safearray of variants...
    VARIANT arr;
    arr.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
    {
        SAFEARRAYBOUND sab[2];
        sab[0].lLbound = 1; sab[0].cElements = 15;
        sab[1].lLbound = 1; sab[1].cElements = 15;
        arr.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab);
    }

    // Fill safearray with some values...
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
            // Create entry value for (i,j)
            VARIANT tmp;
            tmp.vt = VT_I4;
            tmp.lVal = i * j;
            // Add to safearray...
            long indices[] = { i,j };
            SafeArrayPutElement(arr.parray, indices, (void *)&tmp);
        }
    }

    // Get ActiveSheet object
    IDispatch *pXlSheet;
    {
        VARIANT result;
        VariantInit(&result);
        AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlApp, (LPOLESTR)L"ActiveSheet", 0);
        pXlSheet = result.pdispVal;
    }

    // Get Range object for the Range A1:O15...
    IDispatch *pXlRange;
    {
        VARIANT parm;
        parm.vt = VT_BSTR;
        parm.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"A1:O15");

        VARIANT result;
        VariantInit(&result);
        AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlSheet, (LPOLESTR)L"Range", 1, parm);
        VariantClear(&parm);

        pXlRange = result.pdispVal;
    }

    // Set range with our safearray...
    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pXlRange, (LPOLESTR)L"Value", 1, arr);

    // Save workbook
    VARIANT var_result;
    VariantInit(&var_result);
    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &var_result, pXlBook, (LPOLESTR)L"Save", 0);
    VariantClear(&var_result);

    // Release references...
    pUnk->Release();
    pXlRange->Release();
    pXlSheet->Release();
    pXlBook->Release();
    pXlBooks->Release();
    pXlApp->Release();
    VariantClear(&arr);

    printf("All done! Press any key to exit\n");
    getchar();

    // Uninitialize COM for this thread...
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight, а может быть Вы можете подсказать, как можно переделать или добавить в микрософтовский пример по записи данных в Ексель, что бы в екмелл записывались не только данные типа long, но и string ?

Comment: @Optimus1 string преобразуйте в массив WCHAR, добавление в VARIANT делаете как-то так: `tmp.vt = VT_BSTR; tmp.bstrVal = SysAllocString(pArray);` Когда BSTR станет не нужен, освободить его вызовом SysFreeString. Если все еще непонятно, задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight, извините пожалуйста, честно пытался разобраться, но так и не смог :( Как можно было бы осуществить, так сказать обратный процесс, уже не записи данных в Ексель, а чтение эти данных из Екселя ?

Comment: @Optimus1 У свойства Value объекта Range помимо сеттера есть и геттер, который возвращает значение ячейки (или массив значений для диапазона ячеек). Метод AutoWrap в примере от MS универсальный, он позволяет вызывать и методы, и сеттеры, и геттеры. Правда тип возвращаемого variant-а придется определять перебором, и код получится довольно громоздким.

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight, нашел вот такой пример, который читает значение из екселевской ячейки, но только, как тип DOUBLE и все работает, но значение только, как DOUBLE считываеются, а можно ли таким образом считать просто, как String ?:                                                                            
 VARIANT rngResult;
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &rngResult, pXlRange, (LPOLESTR)L"Value", 0);

//Display the value for Range A1
 DOUBLE ival = rngResult.dblVal;
 CString cStr = "Value from cell A1 is: ";
 CString cStr2;

 cStr2.Format(_T("%f"), ival);
 cStr.Append(cStr2);

Comment: @Optimus1 вы можете считать только тот тип, который есть в ячейке. Если там double, то считать можно только double, а не String.

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight, когда формат ячейки ексель числовой и в ячейке одни цифры, то использую DOUBLE, LONG, то все нормально, выводится числовое значение, но когда меняю формат ячейки на текстовый и использую BSTR, то тут все ломается и за место текста в ячейки такое ощущение, что выводится какой то адрес, потому что выводится что то типа - 007F6B44. Не понимаю, почему так, с числами нормально, а с текстом - нет :(

Comment: Разобрался, нужно конвертировать BSTR В string. Спасибо!

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight, подскажите пожалуйста, а где можно почитать про вызовы свойств или методов add, item и прочее функции autowrap ? Функция autowrap она же самописная ?

Comment: @Optimus1 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста ,а как на основе этих данных можно построить график в Excel?

Comment: @Vaizman, думаю, что по ссылке можно найти